# Is there an approximation to a matrix $V = (I-cA)^{-1}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is an adjacency matrix of a connected graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Suppose that we have a fully connected graph of size $N$, each unit with $k$ neighbors. This can be written as an adjacency matrix $A$. Then, let $I$ be an identity matrix of size $N$, with $c \in [0,1]$ a constant.

If we define:

$$
V = (I-cA)^{-1}
$$

is there a way to approximate a general formula for $V$ in terms of $k$ and $N$? Or is there also a way to characterize $V_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ in closed form? Thanks.

Comment: For small values of $c$, the geometric series works well.  In general, you get about $-\log_{10}(c)$ digits of precision per additional term in the series.

Comment: Is there an explicit form or resource for looking at this? thanks

Comment: The approximation is 
$$
V \approx \sum_{k=0}^N c^kA^k
$$
don't know of any resources for this off the top of my head

Comment: How do you define the initial case, $c^0A^0$? Is it zero or 1?

Comment: Right! $c^0A^0 = I$, the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no form in terms of $N$, $k$ and $c$.

Take two admissible matrices A. Note that $f_A(c)=(I-cA)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c^n A^n$ so if $f_A = f_B$ then $A^n$=$B^n$ for all $n$ (because Taylor expansions are unique) but just take two non-isomorphic admissible graphs with the same $N$ and $k$ values.

Relevant: $A^n_{(i,j)}$ is the number of $n$-length walks from $i$ to $j$. Imagine a bug starting at $i$ and moving around the graph. At each edge he has probability $p$ of dying. What is the $\mu$, the expected number of times the bug visits $j$? Well, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n$ where $P_n$ is the probability of the bug being at $j$ at $n$ steps, surviving. There are $k^n$ paths from $i$ and $A^n_{(i,j)}$ paths from $i$ to $j$ so $P_n=p^n A^n_{(i,j)}/k^n$. $\mu = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (p/k)^n * A^n_{(i,j)} = (I-(p/k)A)^{-1}$

Comment: Is there an approximate form here? I have a bit of a hard time understanding how the apply the relevant part you supplied. thanks!

Comment: Clarify what you are asking. There is no function at all for $V$ in terms of $N$, $k$ and $c$. You can give two graphs with the same $N$ and $k$ that give different $V$-values for the same $c$. Your function to find $V$ needs an input of $A$ itself (not just a few graphical properties like $N$ and $k$).
Are you asking for a quick algorithm to derive $V$ based on $A$?
For small values of $c$ you could just compute the first 10 values of $A^n$ which would give you a very good approximation.

The relevant information just gives an application, which might help your intuition.